# Eclipse color themes - java and flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, eclipse, color-scheme

I use Eclipse for both Java and Flex development. Recently, I changed its color scheme to make java code look nicer. But that messed up the flex color scheme somehow.
Is it possible to have my new color scheme for java and default color scheme for flex code? Or, how can i edit the color scheme for flex code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to sort it out with help from this post:
http://polygeek.com/302_flex_changing-font-colors-in-flex-buildereclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can access the Flex syntax coloring via Window -> Preferences -> Flex -> Editors -> Syntax Coloring. It shouldn't interfere with the Java syntax coloring which is located under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring.

Perhaps you changed the general font and color settings under General -> Appearance and General -> Editors, which might have caused the problem. Settings applied there will be globally applied to all editors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using two different workspaces? Every workspace seem to have their own set of options.

Comment: @Jens i need to have both java and flex code open at same time.